# changing value of every cell in dataframe to color the table

Tags: python, pandas, colorama

*Talking about console output only*

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': 1.123, 'b': 'blabla', 'error': True}, {'a': 2.1342, 'b': 'bla', 'error': False}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

What I want to do is to color every cell, based on the value of the "error" cell in the relevant row. i.e. in this case, get this table:

[image]

*For some reason ,this has bad indentation*

I created this table by editing the `data` using `colorama`.

- What I'm looking for is more like `df.loc[df.error, <ALL_COLUMNS>] = colorama.Fore.RED + str(old_value) + colorama.Fore.RESET` (and same for green)

How would I do that?

---

What I tried:

```
for col in df.columns:
   df[col] = df.apply(lambda x: Fore.RED + str(x[col]) + Fore.RESET if x[col] else Fore.GREEN + str(x[col]) + Fore.RESET, axis=1)
```

[image]

[X] indentation is bad, and going column by column which messes up the values

---

`df.apply(lambda x: Fore.RED + str(x['error']) + Fore.RESET if x['error'] else Fore.GREEN + str(x['error']) + Fore.RESET, axis=1)`

[image]

[X] looks better, but I miss all the values

---

```
df.apply(lambda x: Fore.RED + str(x) + Fore.RESET if x['error'] else Fore.GREEN + str(x) + Fore.RESET, axis=1)
```

[image]

[X] logically - works fine. Needs some tweaks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df = df.style.apply(lambda x: np.repeat('color: red' if x['error'] else '', x.shape[0]), axis=1)
```

When output to Excel it looks like...

[image]

Comment: doesn't style work as html? i.e. won't be helpful for console output

Comment: was it just console output you need?

Comment: Yes. I'll add it in the OP

Comment: Oops.  My fault.  I can delete if not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same as CIsForCookies and color cells of a dataframe in a cmd console window. I took the same approach by adding colorama color tags to the df cells, which also messed up resp. misaligned the printed dataframe. I also tried to insert rich color tags, which caused the same misalignment.

Then I found this discussion on the pandas GitHub page about [styling console/terminal output](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18066) So, manipulating the dataframe for getting colors doesn´t seem to work.

But the rich module was mentioned in the last post and I know you can create colorful tables with it. So I tried pulling the last rows of my df to a json object, iterate through the json data and add colors where I need them and build a rich table out of this altered json data - and it worked :-)

Some code...

1. Get the last 10 rows of df as an interable json data

   `json_data = loads(df.tail(10).to_json(orient='index'))`
2. As an example, iterate through the json data and add green or red color background if the close is above or below the 20 EMA:

   `for index in json_data:
        if json_data[index]['close'] >= json_data[index]['20EMA']:
            json_data[index]['20EMA'] = f"[black on green]{json_data[index]['20EMA']}[/]"
        else:
            json_data[index]['20EMA'] = f"[black on red]{json_data[index]['20EMA']}[/]"`
3. Create a rich table and add rows from the json data:

   `for index in json_data:
        table.add_row(index,
                    str(local_time),
                    str(f"{json_data[index]['close']:.2f}"),
                    str(int(json_data[index]['volume'])),
                    str(json_data[index]['20EMA']),
                    )`

And finally, there you have a table from a df with different cell colors.

[image: df with cell colors]